# Sort js object by name

Tags: sorting

I'd like to sort objects by prop name, eg

```
const a = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "asd",
    headers: {
        Content: "application/json",
        Authorization: "token",
    },
}
```

then select only the object in the buffer, apply our function, and it would turn into

```
const a = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "token",
        Content: "application/json",
    },
    method: "GET",
    url: "asd",
}
```

I know there's a `sort-regexp-fields`

Answer (score 4):

If your JavaScript code happened to also be valid JSON like:

```
{
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "asd",
    "headers": {
        "Content": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "token"
    }
}
```

You could use the function `json-pretty-print-buffer-ordered` or `json-pretty-print-ordered` from `json.el`.  These functions won't work with most JavaScript code though because JSON has a stricter syntax.  The sample code has unquoted keys and trailing commas which are perfectly valid JavaScript features (you just can't use JSON tools on it).

By no means is this a complete solution to your question (but it might be useful for some circumstances, so I figured it worth mentioning).

Comment: yes, I mean, is a js object, not a json

Comment: @DanielPérez Sorry; I didn't mean to imply that there was anything wrong with your question or the code.  I mention the json function since it might be useful for some edge cases.

Comment: nothing to be sorry about ;) @ebpa , i find this answer useful, I searched for other similar questions and they suggested the use of `json-pretty-print-buffer-ordered`, I was hoping someone had to deal with this before ..., I think i'll take a different approach and just pass the region to other program that would parse it correctly. thanks btw